# Backbone.js where to place logic

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

Using backbone.js and it's navigation/routes, and loading html template pages in from external files as we navigate around.  The javascript for these pages are all excluded in one large javascript file for the entire app.

What are the tradeo-offs of moving the logic into  tag in the file that we are placing on the page?

So far:
Good:

- smaller files, less loading

Bad:

- mixing javascript logic with html

Comment: When you say "moving the logic into tags in the file that we are placing on the page" do you mean that you want to put your JavaScript logic into external templates that you are using for your views?

Comment: I mean, in the external files, within the html, place a <script /> tag to include logic for that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really aim to keep your views (HTML, CSS, and templates) separate from your logic (JavaScript code).  Otherwise, it will become really difficult to evolve your application as it grows and/or reuse code from one page to the next.

You might want to take a look at modularizing your Javascript with something like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/).  This chapter in Developing Backbone.js Applications should help you get started: http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#advanced.  Require.js has an optimizer which will deal combining and minifying your scripts for production, so that begins to address the size and loading issues.

Comment: this is perfect, feels like it was written to solve my problem, thanks!